# error in spyder anaconda IDE while using pip install for installing modules

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, ide, spyder

i'm trying to install a python module in spyder anaconda IDE.

> pip install cowsay

but every time there is an error like this :

> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
> 'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It's not advisable to install packages within Spyder. Instead, please close Spyder, open the Anaconda Prompt, run there `pip install cowsay` and then start Spyder again. That should fix this problem for you.

Comment: yes .i think stand alone installation of spyder is not a good idea.